Why does a Java method with a interface type fails to recognize this overloaded method?
I'm studying for a exam and came across the following problem:
IntfX is a interface in package A, and contains the method public void op_a(Double e)
CIsY is a class in package A that implements IntfX and overrides op_a.
In package B, the Main class imports package A, extends CIsY and proceeds to overload op_a as public void op_a(Double e, Double f)
Now in the psvm block, there's two instantiations: Intfx a = new Main(), and Main b = new Main()
Them it proceeds to call a.op_a(Double e, Double f) and c.op_a(Double e, Double f)
The a.op_a call fails. It shows a compilation time error "expect 1 arguments but found 2"
My question is: why does the a object fails to use the overloaded method op_a with 2 arguments? In another problems, when there's two versions of a method, the jvm gives preference to the object, not the type.
The code:
`package A:
public interface IntfX {
        public void op_a(Double a);
        public void op_b(Double b);
    }


public class CIsY implements IntfX {
    protected double v = 0.0;
    String p = null;

    public CIsY(Double x, String b) {
        v = x;
        p = b;
    }

    public void op_a(Double a) {
        v += a;
    }

    public void op_b(Double b) {
        v -= b;
    }

    public void op_c() {
        v = 0.0;
        p = null;
    }
}


Package B:
import pack_a.*;

public class Main extends CIsY{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntfX a = new Main();
        CIsY b = new Main();
        Men c = new Main();

        c.op_a(0.5,0.8);
        a.op_a(0.0, 0.1);
    }
    public Main() {
        super(0.0, "");
    }

    public void op_a(Double e, Double f) {
        v = e + f;
    }

    public void  op_b(Double e, Double f) {
        v = e + f;
    }

    public void op_K(Double d) {
        v = d;
    }
}

I expected to a.op_a be able to recognize the overloaded method and compile.

what is the type of a? (which object type is it guaranteed to hold)

If I write IntfX a = random() ? new Main() : new CIsY();, then what method does a.op_a(0.0, 0.1); call?

I'm sure there's a duplicate (even many) that I haven't found yet, but... The type of the variable a is IntfX, and that type doesn't have that method.  It's really as simple as that.  Any given implementing type which gets assigned to that variable may have that method, or may not, or may have any other methods.  That's irrelevant.  The compiler can only guarantee that a has methods on IntfX because that's the type used for that variable.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53261487/java-type-system-why-do-these-assignments-method-calls-and-type-casts-fail

It took me a while to understand what "the psvm block" meant. Just say the main method.

Because the point of an interface is to enforce the implementation of the specified methods, and that was not done in the Main class.
In your example, your interface IntfX explicitly states:

That you must have two methods called 'op_a' and 'op_b'.
That both methods must return void.
That both methods must accept one argument of type Double, with variable names 'a' and 'b' respectively.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html
Java allows for Overloading Methods, simply put this means that each method implemented within an object must be unique in at least one of two ways:

The method's name is unique
The method's list of parameters (by type), is unique

This means that when you "overload a method" you are actually just creating a new separate method that happens to have the same name. It's simply that Java's compiler is smart enough to recognize that they are different methods DESPITE the methods having the same name.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

BTW the problem in the question is not restricted to interfaces (nor to overloaded methods) - similar behavior is expected with a classes (Object i = new Integer(123); int value = i.intValue(); will not compile)

BTW "with variable names 'a' and 'b'" - parameter names do not matter, only their types

@user85421 I updated this, but I don't understand your comment from May
